# How do you copy an image from an adobe PDF and paste it into word without losing its quality?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images

I have a PDF documents with photos and when I right click and “copy image” and go into the word document and “paste”, the photo quality is a little blurry. It’s not the same quality as the image in the PDF. Is there a way to fix this? Is this an Adobe issue or Word issue? Currently using Windows 10.

Comment: I am using Adobe Acrobat (newest) and Word 365 all up to date. I opened the PDF, chose Export, then to Word and the resulting image was the same size in Word and the same clarity. Try using the Export function.

Comment: Also try opening the PDF directly in Word (Word, open, browse to PDF, and convert).

Comment: Do these working methods work for you?

Comment: Did you try just dragging it instead of copying?

Comment: you can also try saving the pdf as pics &then inserting into word

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be at either or both ends of transfer.

If you zoom to 100% (actual size) in any PDF viewer, and select an image it "should" paste at the same density, HOWEVER Word may alter that density to say if lucky 50% or worse an arbitrary zoom density that needs more interpolation.

So the input for Word should in MSpaint be precise pixel perfect.

[image]

The problem arises on pasting as 100% quality of exact pixel placements is not accepted

[image]

***If you Paste at exactly 50% and view at 200% it should still look the same.***

[image]

so at 50% it looks worse if we cut and paste again
[image]

And extracted from the word document, no mater how large we zoom, that can now be shown by the reduced size, thus it was the paste into a word Processor that causes the problem.

[image]

In some cases such behaviour can be avoided by OLE.

Here we see that we can Click the image and
its the ORIGINAL FULL QUALITY IMAGE

[image]

The embeding was done in 26  year old Word97 but the point is that it works well across all versions of MS  word so even a smaller copy from a Word Viewer will retain a good image.
[image]